# Tail recursive Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, knuth-morris-pratt

I've created a simple implementation of [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) in Scala. Now I want to get fancy and do the same thing in tail-recursive manner. My gut feeling says it shouldn't be too difficult (both the table and the search parts), yet that same feeling also tells me that this must have been done already by someone, probably smarter than myself. Hence the question. Do you know of any tail-recursive implementation of Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm?

```
object KnuthMorrisPrattAlgorithm {
  def search(s: String, w: String): Int = {
    if (w.isEmpty) {
      return 0
    }

    var m = 0
    var i = 0
    val t = table(w)

    while(m + i < s.length) {
      if (w(i) == s(m + i)) {
        if (i == w.length - 1) {
          return m
        }
        i += 1
      } else {
        if (t(i) > -1) {
          i = t(i)
          m += i - t(i)
        } else {
          i = 0
          m += 1
        }
      }
    }

    return -1
  }

  def table(w: String): Seq[Int] = {
    var pos = 2
    var cnd = 0
    val t = Array(-1, 0) ++ Array.fill(w.size - 2)(0)

    while (pos < w.length) {
      if (w(pos - 1) == w(cnd)) {
        cnd += 1
        t(pos) = cnd
        pos += 1
      } else if (cnd > 0) {
        cnd = t(cnd)
      } else {
        t(pos) = 0
        pos += 1
      }
    }

    t
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what that algorithm does, but here are your functions, tail-recursivized:

```
object KnuthMorrisPrattAlgorithm {
  def search(s: String, w: String): Int = {
    if (w.isEmpty) {
      return 0
    }

    val t = table(w)

    def f(m: Int, i: Int): Int = {
      if (m + i < s.length) {
        if (w(i) == s(m + i)) {
          if (i == w.length - 1) {
            m
          } else {
            f(m, i + 1)
          }
        } else {
          if (t(i) > -1) {
            f(m + i - t(i), t(i))
          } else {
            f(m + 1, 0)
          }
        }
      } else {
        -1
      }
    }

    f(0, 0)
  }

  def table(w: String): Seq[Int] = {
    val t = Array(-1, 0) ++ Array.fill(w.size - 2)(0)

    def f(pos: Int, cnd: Int): Array[Int] = {
      if (pos < w.length) {
        if (w(pos - 1) == w(cnd)) {
          t(pos) = cnd + 1
          f(pos + 1, cnd + 1)
        } else if (cnd > 0) {
          f(pos, t(cnd))
        } else {
          t(pos) = 0
          f(pos + 1, cnd)
        }
      } else {
        t
      }
    }

    f(2, 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a deeper look at it and run some tests latter today. Btw, how did you do that without knowing the underlying algorithm? Is there any technique to mechanically convert loops to tail-recursive functions?

Comment: Tail-recursion is about using the arguments to represent the state of execution. I made the local variables parameters to the tail-recursive  function, and then instead of *changing* the variables, I passed in their new values to the function, recursively.

Comment: Compiler complains about the second example about t in line `cnd = t(cnd)`

Comment: @ViliusNormantas, yes, I actually tossed that. It wasn't much better than the original :P

Comment: It passed my unit test, so I'm accepting the answer. 
Thanks again.

Comment: However, I think there should be a more elegant solution. As we are searching in string s, we could drop the characters which we've tested  and run the search function recursivelly with the remaining string (we could use List of Chars to make it really efficient). I'll try that latter.

Comment: Also I've added @tailrec to the inner functions, and the compiler didn't complain.